# Multilingual Text to Speech Libraries?

Tags: c#, internationalization, text-to-speech

I'm currently looking at developing a small client that has the ability to read text to speech in a variety of languages. Mainly targeting English & Japanese.

So my question is, does anyone know of a library that is capable of reading English and Japanese to speech?

My target development language initially, is c#

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft Speech API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125663(VS.85).aspx), if you have the right voices (you can [buy](http://www.microsoft.com/speech/evaluation/thirdparty/engines.mspx) them, free voices are often of poor quality. Windows ships by default with an English voice).

You can find some free SAPI voices [here](http://www.bytecool.com/voices.htm).

You can listen to [Loquendo TTS](http://www.loquendo.com/en/demos/demo_tts.htm) to hear the voices quality.

TTS is really easy with SAPI (when set, it's a one liner).

There's a .NET port :

> The .NET 3.0 Framework has included a
>   managed speech API, System.Speech.
>   This allows you to rapidly create
>   speech-enabled Windows applications
>   for Windows Vista using Visual Studio
>   2005. As with all versions of SAPI, this version is dependent on the
>   operating system. SAPI 5.3 is only
>   available on Windows Vista. As with
>   previous versions of SAPI, your
>   application can run on earlier
>   versions, such as Windows XP's SAPI
>   5.1, however, if your application uses any features specific to SAPI 5.3,
>   expect a not-supported error.
>
> The two main namespaces to become
>   familiar with for .NET speech-enabled
>   applications are
>   System.Speech.Synthesis and
>   System.Speech.Recognition

http://reddevnews.com/articles/2007/02/15/give-applications-a-voice.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Speech APIs built into Windows XP/Vista support Text to Speech in English, Japanese, and many more languages.

Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx) for a tutorial:

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind calling a web service you could use the speech synthesis from the Microsoft translator API [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512420%28v=MSDN.10%29.aspx). This [blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/03/22/silverlight-translator-text-to-speech-api.aspx) has an C# Silverlight example using the translator and TTS features.